# How to resolve class name conflict in java?

Tags: java, namespaces, overriding

I'm writing a compiler in Java, I have an abstract class `Type`, and I want to have a `String` class to extend my `Type`.

However, I already have a `CharacterType` class that uses some methods from `java.lang.String`, so there will be some name conflicts when I have `length()` and `charAt(index)` methods in my local `String` class.

I could easily resolve this conflict by naming my self-defined `String` class as `StringType`, but I want to know how to override the entire class if I still want to name my class as `String`.

Comment: You can avoid conflict by using the fully qualified class name `java.lang.String`. But it's a really bad idea.

Comment: Please don't use the name `String` for a class of your own.  You're just asking for disaster.  And readability and maintainability crash and burn.

Comment: @shmosel, I need the length() and charAt to generate my LLVM IR. So I think David and you are correct, I should avoid using the name `String`.

Comment: @DavidWallace You are right, there will be a list of methods that I have to override, which is pretty risky.